# Making Smarty supporting multiple languages

Tags: php, smarty, multilingual

first of all, let me tell ya, that I'm from Germany. So my English will not be very well. Please forgive me. =P

I'm about to develop a multilingual website with PHP5. In order to seperate the presentation layer from the business logic, I'm using the [SmartyTemplateEngine](http://www.smarty.net/) (v3.0.8). To make it multilingual I had to edit [this SmartyPlugin](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyMultilanguageSupport) sometimes. But finally it is working for me. I'm using it that way:

`{lang}language.string{/lang}`.

In the language file I have:

`language.string = <![CDATA[Hello world!]]>` (So it says Hello world!)

Works fine. But I want to expend the script a bit further. I want to pass a variable to the language string. Something like this:

`{lang s=$userName}language.string{/lang}`

In the language file I want to have:

`language.string = <![CDATA[Hello %s!]]>` (So it says Hello username!)

I tried to find my solution with Google, but I didn't find something good. As far as I'm not a professional in PHP, I'm not capable of editing it myself. I hope somebody can help me with that. It is bothering me quite a while...

Greets,
Basti

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I'm not using this plugin, but had to do the same thing. I figuered out that for my needs the following was the best solution:

In an XML file I define my strings (this example is `xml/en/content.xml`):

```
<translations>
    <translation id="hello_world"><![CDATA[Hello ##username##!]]></translation>
    <translation id="how_are_you"><![CDATA[How are you?]]></translation>
</translations>
```

In my `Localizer` class I initialize these translations and save them in an array. The `translate` function gets the ID string from smarty, searches for the id in its translations and for any `##string##` text. These `##...##` will be replaced with variables already assigned to smarty.

```
class Localizer {

    private static $translations = array();

    public static function init($language) {

        $temp_content = simplexml_load_file('xml/' . $language . '/content.xml');
        foreach ($temp_content as $key => $value){
            self::$translations[(string)$value['id']] = (string)$value;
        }

    }

    public static function translate($params, $name, $smarty) {

         $translation = '';
         if( ! is_null($name) && array_key_exists($name, self::$translations)) {

            // get variables in translation text
            $translation = self::$translations[$name];
            preg_match_all('/##([^#]+)##/i', $translation, $vars, PREG_SET_ORDER);

            // replace with assigned smarty values
            foreach($vars as $var) {
                $translation = str_replace($var[0], $smarty->getTemplateVars($var[1]), $translation);
            }

        }

        return $translation;

    }

}
```

Now you have to tell smarty which function it should use. This could be your `index.php`:

```
include('Localizer.class.php');
Localizer::init('en');
$smarty->registerPlugin('block', 'translate', array('Localizer', 'translate'), true);
```

To use the translations, first, I assign the username:

```
$smarty->assign('username', $username);
```

In the template file:

```
{translate}hello_world{/translate}
```

Hope this helps, greetings from austria :)

Comment: @Sascha Galley 

I really appreciate your help. Its awesome. But I have no idea, of what Localizer Class you're talking about. I searched my whole smarty folder. There is no Localizer Class. Can you help me with that too? Do you use another plugin? Maybe that one? 

http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=LocalizerPlugin

Comment: @Basti its a class i build on my own. edited the answer, hope its clear now.

Comment: @Sascha Galley Ah, okay. That makes sense. I'm really sorry for being so stupid. I can't make it running. I did now the following:

I created a Localizer.class.php in the same directory as the Smarty.class.php. That contains your code above. So, now I do not know where to put the translation function? I guess it should garantue that, the function in the template will work out. So how to do it? I can't put a function into the function.translation.php right? Sry, for not getting it...

Comment: @Basti edited it again...the translate function belongs also in the localizer class

Comment: @Sascha Galley That is really embarassing. You explained it very well and I can't get in working. Now - after your last edit - I have the Localizer.class.php in my Smarty.class.php directory. Than I edited the pathes and I thought about it, I get the language code with the $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']. Works very fine. But on the page there is simply appearing nothing... No error, but no text as well. 

I did {translate}hello_world{/translate} and there is simpley nothing... What may be me mistake?

Comment: @Basti forgot to say `init('en')` with en in it. if you use `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` it probably will be 'en-gb' or 'de-de', so you need a folder with 'en-gb'. try it first with the init('en'), create a file 'xml/en/content.xml' and run `var_dump(Localizer::translate(array(), 'hello_world', $smarty));` to see if it outputs anything.

Comment: @Sascha Galley True. I forgot to say, that I get wit substr() the right country code. Tested it with echo. Your test with var_dump() shows me nothing but an empty string. So something seems to be wrong with me pathes, I guess? But I looked it up, it is like this:

project/libs/Smarty.class.php
project/libs/Localizer.class.php
project/lang/de.xml
project/index.php
project/templates/index.tpl

Of course I edited the path in the Localizer class to that: 
`('../lang/' . $language . '.xml');`

For testing purposes I tried ../lang/de.xml - even then there is no output. What may be the mistake?

Comment: @Basti since you are including from index.php you don't need `..` in the path for the language. try that, and in the `Localizer::init()` write `var_dump($temp_content);` after `$temp_content` is set, to see if xml content is properly loaded.

Comment: @Sascha Galley Oh, thats interesting. I put var_dump($temp_content); right after the setting of the variable and after I call the page in the browser, I simply see nothing (just the normal template). There is not printing anything, not even empty strings or something. Seems to be, there is no init of your class? 

I'm really thankful, hope we get that go. I really appreciate your help, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Sascha Galley Finally I made it working! I really thank you!!! That was surely hard for ya! =P I don't know what to say, it works awsome. Just like I had in mind! THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: This helped me a lot. +1 but where is the `<![CDATA[` for? Can't it be `<translation id="hello_world">Hello ##username##!</translation>`? Its working but maby i forget something.

Comment: You will need CDATA as soon as you use tags in your translations (e.g. <a> or <img>). To avoid any conflicts later on, I usually always write CDATA.